# 2sxc: Adding more content templates in the same page does replicate link tags for css and js

Tags: 2sxc

I'm new to dnn and 2sxc.
Just wondering if I'm adding for example a card template (image,some text, a link), adding in the html template link tag to css/js, when adding that content more times in the page obviously the link tags are replicate in page source and it isn't so nice.
For example:

```
  <script src="[App:Path]/script.js" type="text/javascript" data-enableoptimizations="100"></script>
```

it is going to be replicate in page.
Maybe I'm missing something, there is a better way to do it?
Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tried it, you should see that it will only be included once, IF you have the data-enableoptimizations included :)

So allready taken care of

Comment: Thanks you for your reply.. I included the data-enableoptimizations="100", but looking at my generated page code i see the link tag replicated for each time there is a content template in the page... What I'm missing? 
Thanks you

Comment: so at first, please use ...="true" by default, the number is only a good idea when you want to actively control the sequence of various scripts.

Comment: then - just to prevent typo-issues and similar - please try it on one of our demo-apps, like the blog. just to check if it fails all the time, or just on your templates.

Comment: btw: if the enable... works, then you should at least get your url changed to include a ?cdv=### on each url. is that the case?

Comment: ok, I'm trying to get this sorted in content templates because I'm not yet using apps.
I tryed with data-enableoptimizations="true", but looking at my generated source code in homepage, where I'm using just contents i get link tag 11 times:
link rel="stylesheet" href="/Portals/0/2sxc/Content/style.css" data-enableoptimizations="true"/>

Comment: I see the ?cdv=### for styles in the head section but there isn't any about contents of 2sxc

Comment: this is working, like you said for scripts, i see just one in the head with ?cvd=##

<script src="/Portals/0/2sxc/Content/script.js?cdv=55" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i found the issue...
When I edit a template, selecting Html snippets in the combo to the right, then click on css, style-sheet it is writing a demo link tag, but it is not adding the type (type="text/css"), without it seems not work..
Maybe it could be fixed in a next release :)

Comment: note that the link-tag could be used for non-stylesheets as well, in which case it shouldn't land in the optimizations. So I believe the type-check is necessary - see for example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Comment: Yeah you are right, maybe the snippets could be more specifics, for example "css links", but I understand that this a low priority thing :)
Thanks you!

Comment: the snippets are all in an excel in the code repo. it would be great if you could enhance them and push the result back